# Reorganize Pyspark dataframe: Create new column using row element

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to map document with this structure to dataframe.

```
   root
     |-- Id: "a1"
     |-- Type: "Work"
     |-- Tag: Array
     |    |--0: Object 
     |    |   |-- Tag.name : "passHolder"
     |    |   |-- Tag.value : "Jack Ryan"
     |    |   |-- Tag.stat : "verified"
     |    |-- 1: Object
     |    |   |-- Tag.name : "passNum"
     |    |   |-- Tag.value : "1234"
     |    |   |-- Tag.stat : "unverified"
     |-- version: 1.5
```

By exploding the array using `explode_outer`,flattening struct and renaming using `.col` + `alias`, the dataframe will look like:

```
df = df.withColumn("Tag",F.explode_outer("Tag"))
df = df.select(col("*"), 
       .col("Tag.name").alias("Tag_name"),
       .col("Tag.value").alias("Tag_value"),
       .col("Tag.stat").alias("Tag_stat")).drop("Tag")

+--+----+-----------+-----------+---------+---------+
|Id|Type| Tag_name  | Tag_value |Tag_stat | version |
+--+----+-----------+-----------+---------+---------+
 a1 Work  passHolder  Jack Ryan  verified       1.5
 a1 Work  passNum      1234      unverified     1.5
```

I am trying to reorganise the df structure so that it's more query-able,by making certain row element as column name and populate it with relevant values.
Can anyone help to give pointers/steps required to arrive at desired output format like below? Thank you very much for the advise.

Target format:

```
+--+----+-----------------+-----------------+-------------+------------+--------+
|Id|Type| Tag_passHolder  | passHolder_stat | Tag_passNum |passNum_stat||version|
+--+----+-----------------+-----------------+-------------+------------+--------+
 a1 Work   Jack Ryan          verified           1234       unverified     1.5
```

Comment: sounds like a simple join. have you tried it?

Comment: @Steven I haven't. Can you help expand on how to accomplish target sparkdf using joins ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the output df you displayed, I would do something like this :

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

passholder_df = df.select(
    "ID",
    "Type",
    F.col("Tag_value").alias("Tag_passHolder"),
    F.col("Tag_stat").alias("passHolder_stat"),
    "version",
).where("Tag_name = 'passHolder'")

passnum_df = df.select(
    "ID",
    "Type",
    F.col("Tag_value").alias("Tag_passNum"),
    F.col("Tag_stat").alias("passNum_stat"),
    "version",
).where("Tag_name = 'passNum'")

passholder_df.join(passnum_df, on=["ID", "Type", "version"], how="full")
```

You probably need to work a little bit on the join condition, depending on your business rules.

Comment: I got your approach here @Steven, thanks. In the case where `Tag` array is dynamic & can have many more objects with same structs, is it possible to (recursively?) retrieve `Tag.name` value to as new column & populate it with `Tag.value` for that every object?